# Order based on the number present in the text

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

this is my first time using this site. I am working on a code, which I am trying to solve. I am unable to get the output as required. This is about sorting arrays. I know that I should be using `array.sort()`, but I have to use a custom code to sort them because, the string I have is:

```
is2 Thi1s T4est 3a
```

And I am converting this string into array using `array = str.split(" ")` and the challenge in this is, I need to find the number in it. So what I am trying to do really is, getting the number using:

```
parseInt(array[i]);
```

It works only once or twice. For e.g., for the above string, it gives me:

```
parseInt(array[0]);  // NaN
parseInt(array[1]);  // NaN
parseInt(array[2]);  // NaN
parseInt(array[3]);  // 3
```

I am not sure how I could reliably take the number from the string. Should I use `RegEx` or something for this?

Comment: Yes, regexp is the best idea.
``var r = /\d+/g;
"is2 Thi1s T4est 3a".match(r)``

Comment: You can (and should) still use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Just provide a `compareFunction`. There is more information in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really appreciate for giving such a detailed explanation. The first issue is using `parseInt()` will not work, if the number is hidden inside after the first character. So to get the number from the text, please replace your `parseInt()` code with the following:

```
array[i].match(/(\d+)/)[0]
```

This is a **Regular Expression**, which reads the string and gets the matching number from the array.

```
array[0].match(/(\d+)/)[0]  // 2
array[1].match(/(\d+)/)[0]  // 1
array[2].match(/(\d+)/)[0]  // 4
array[3].match(/(\d+)/)[0]  // 3
```

Now since you need to order them based on the numbers, you can do this way. You need to put them in the right order based on the numbers, let's have a final array defined this way:

```
var finalArray = [];
```

We need to start filling each of the entries with the right index, based on the value that you received from the array. i.e.:

```
finalArray[0] = "Thi1s";
finalArray[1] = "is2";
finalArray[2] = "3a";
finalArray[3] = "T4est";
```

To make this, we can either loop or use a `forEach()` function. I love to use a map function, but it's heavier than `forEach`, while many prefer loop. So, the function looks like this:

```
array.forEach(function (value) {
  // Value here is the current value. Could be Thi1s or something.
  finalArray[parseInt(array[i].match(/(\d+)/)[0])] = value;
});
```

Now that we have filled in the `finalArray`, it's time to join them and send it as return value.

```
return finalArray.join(" "); // Join each with a space.
```

The complete code will be looking like:

```js
function getSortedValues(str) {
  var finalArray = [];
  str.split(" ").forEach(function (v) {
    if (!!v)
      finalArray[parseInt(v.match(/(\d+)/)[0])] = v;
  });
  return finalArray.join(" ").trim();
}

console.log(getSortedValues("is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"));
```

Comment: @4castle `undefined` values? Why?

Comment: @4castle So the ... Wait.. I am not storing the output of `.map()` anywhere. It won't cause any issues right?

Comment: @4castle Got it. `:)`

Comment: @4castle Updated.

Comment: @4castle *facepalm* instance for me. LoL.

Comment: Thank you Praveen for the detailed response!

Comment: This method of sorting will remove duplicates from the array though. Two strings can't use the same number.

Comment: @4castle Yea, that's what would be the condition right? Generally. This looks like some quiz stuff.

Answer (score 2):

`parseInt()` will only parse a number at the beginning of the string, not in the middle. Use a regexp to find the number. This will find the first number anywhere in the string:

```
var match = str.match(/\d+/);
var number = match ? parseInt(match[0]) : 0;
```

Comment: Isn't the question about ordering? `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar The question mainly seems to be about getting the number. The ordering can be done using `sort()` where the comparison function uses this to get the numbers and compare them.

Comment: Ah, okay... My bad... `:)` Actually I took a different RegEx approach. Is mine correct? It's working anyway? `:D`

Comment: Try changing the example so you have `10` in one of the words, to see if it's ordering it correctly.

Comment: I get you now. LoL. Updated the answer with `\d+` will it work now?

Answer (score 1):

> This is about sorting arrays.

The solution using `String.prototype.match()`, `Array.prototype.sort()` and `String.prototype.localeCompare()`(with *numeric collation*) functions:

```js
var s = 'is2 Thi1s T4est 3a',
    words = s.split(' ');

words.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.match(/\d+/)[0].localeCompare(b.match(/\d+/)[0], 'kn');
});

console.log(words.join(' '));
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

---

The alternative sorting approach would be:

```
...
words.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.match(/\d+/)[0];
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it use the `kn` locale so it sorts the strings numerically?

Comment: What's `kn` @Barmar?

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare: **Whether numeric collation should be used, such that "1" < "2" < "10". Possible values are "true" and "false".**

Comment: My suggestion is that it could just be `return a.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.match(/\d+/)[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `split` you could use `match` to get the words in an array, but only the word parts that start with a digit.

In a second step you can then do the `parseInt` or in one go with `map(parseFloat)`:

```js
var str = 'is2 Thi1s T4est 3a';
var array = str.match(/\d\S*/g);
console.log(array);
array = array.map(parseFloat);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If poster has more than 1 digit in a chunk this will miss to catch it. Probably this regex `str.match(/\d+/g);` will suit better.

Comment: No it will not miss it. `\S*` will still also match a next digit. However, it will ignore a second distinct group of digits occurring in the same word (`parsetInt/Float` will ignore it), which was my intent, as I see the OP expects one output per word.

Comment: Why do you want to match the next character if it's not a digit?

Comment: See my explanation in above comment.

Comment: Ahh, so if he has a word like `a12bc34` it will only return `12`, not `12` and `34`.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I aimed for.

Comment: But you could just split the string into words, and then use `\d+` in each word to get its first number. I think those are what he wants to sort.

Comment: Indeed, you could do that too. There are many ways to approach this.